# Traefik - redirect not work with PathPrefixStrip without slash

Tags: traefik

i need redirect a specific `/path`, i write this compose:

```
web1:
    image: httpd
    labels:
      - "traefik.backend=httpd"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:www.example.com"
      - "traefik.port=80"
web2:
    image: nginx
    labels:
      - "traefik.backend=nginx"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:www.foobar.com"
      - "traefik.port=80"   
app:
    image: custom/image
    labels:
      - "traefik.backend=app"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:www.example.com,www.foobar.com; PathPrefixStrip:/app"
      - "traefik.port=80"
```

When i go to `http://www.example.com/app` and `http://www.foobar.com/app` i need go into container `app`, but work only if i insert a `/` at the end of URL:

`http://www.example.com/app` not work

`http://www.foobar.com/app` not work

`http://www.example.com/app/` work

`http://www.foobar.com/app/` work

I have already a version of this app that work with an apache alias, I suppose it's not a problem of the app

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution here: https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/563#issuecomment-421360934

```
labels:
  - "traefik.frontend.redirect.regex=^(.*)/path$"
  - "traefik.frontend.redirect.replacement=$1/path/"
  - "traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefix:/path;ReplacePathRegex: ^/path/(.*) /$1"
```